# I have a problem with my sound on my dell xps 13 9343

Tags: sound, windows, dell, 15.10, xps

[Dell XPS 13 9343, bIOS A07 and kernel 4.2] Tried many things and nothing worked in a permanent manner. I feel like I have the same exact problem as this guy, but with Ubuntu 15.10 : http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19667114?autolike=16020208-672a762d-a477-4dd4-8648-328bcf8afcc5
As there is no answer by now and I experience issues with my sound on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10, I post this thread. I think it's not an hardware problem, because it works sometimes as described in the post. Hope someone has an answer. Maybe both OS sound problems aren't reliated... I can post screenshots as you want and post anything you need to help me resolve the problem. Just keep in mind that I'm not that experienced with linux.

Answer (score 0):

Which kernel are you using? There is a severe bug with kernel 4.4 (or newer). It affects all distros. See this Fedora bug report:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1313434

I suggest you file a bug with Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm using kernel 4.2 and Dell doesn't seem to be worried by this bug. I know it's not an hardware problem. I uninstalled Ubuntu 15.10 to install 14.04 and it didn't solve my problem. Really deceiving from Dell